# WFC web service executing a SQL Server stored-procedure with permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, wcf, stored-procedures

I have to develop a WCF web service using C# and .NET framework 4.5 that executes a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure with permission granted to a Windows account, published in IIS 7.5, and the WS returning an array of values.

The web service is developed but I'm stuck with authentication. How do I ask the Windows credentials in the WS and use them to execute the stored procedure? It doesn't have to implement transport or message level security. I'm testing it with a C# and .NET framework 4.5 client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What resources have you found on this topic elsewhere, and why haven't they solved your problem?

Comment: The key search terms you need are 'WCF Windows Authentication' and 'WCF Impersonation'.  Google those and you should find everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Dont  know if this helps a quick search i got this

ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity gets user